# azure Data factory migrate SQL Server database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I know how to copy data from a database to another, but in one step I must create the exact table in the source db to the destination db.

Is there a method in data factory to migrate a SQL server database to SQL Azure without creating all the tables in the destination database or is Data Factory just for copying data between the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Data Factory to copy data or copy delta changes from a SQL Server database to an Azure SQL Database as explained on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-powershell) tutorial. You can also put data coming from on-premise SQL Server to Azure BLOB storage and from there upload data to Azure SQL database as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-sql-azure-adf).